# How to SELECT WHERE IN ALL elements of list

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I have an entity `Entry` which has following relations:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "entryList", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    private List<Tag> tags = new LinkedList<>();
```

This SELECT statement selects all `Entry` where in the relation `tags` is at least **one** element from the list `list`:

```
SELECT m FROM Entry m JOIN m.tags tags WHERE tags IN :list;
```

But what I want is a SELECT statement to select all `Entry` where **all** elements of `list` must be in relation `tags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a subquery and a count,

```
Select e from Entry e where (Select count(t) from Tag t, Entry e2 join e2.tags t2 where t2 = t and e = e2 and t.id in (:ids)) = :size
```

Where ids are the ids of the tags (you may be able to use the objects as well), and :size is the size of the tags collections.

If you tag has an inverse m-m to entry you can use,

```
Select e from Entry e where (Select count(t) from Tag t join t.entries e2 where e = e2 and t.id in (:ids)) = :size
```

Comment: Thank you. Good idea to use a subquery and a count!